# Unpacking varargin to individual variables

Tags: function, matlab, arguments

I'm writing a wrapper to a function that takes varargin as its inputs.  I want to preserve the function signature in the wrapper, but nesting `varargin` causes all the variable to be lumped together.

```
function inner(varargin) %#ok<VANUS>
% An existing function
disp(nargin)
end

function outer(varargin)
% My wrapper
inner(varargin);
end

outer('foo', 1:3, {})   % Uh-oh, this is 1
```

I need a way to unpack `varargin` in the outer function, so that I have a list of individual variables.  There is a really nasty way to do this by constructing a string of the names of the variables to pass the `inner`, and calling `eval`.

```
function outer2(varargin) %#ok<VANUS>
% My wrapper, second attempt
inputstr = '';
for i = 1:nargin
   inputstr = [inputstr 'varargin{' num2str(i) '}']; %#ok<AGROW>
   if i < nargin
      inputstr = [inputstr ', ']; %#ok<AGROW>
   end
end    
eval(['inner(' inputstr ')']);
end

outer2('foo', 1:3, {})   % 3, as it should be
```

Can anyone think of a less hideous way of doing things, please?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The call in inner in outer should instead be

```
inner(varargin{:})
```

In other words, expand varargin into the comma-separated list for the call to inner.  Then you can avoid all the mess.

Comment: Out of curiosity, is there an equivalent way of splitting arrays? Like a nicer version of `c = arrayfun(@(x) x, 1:3, 'UniformOutput', false); c{:}`.

Comment: Not sure it's nicer, but you can use variants of cell2mat perhaps.  What's the matter with arrayfun, cryptic?  You could also use a for loop if you preallocate the output.  I don't think performance would be a big issue for reasonable size arrays.